# Problems with pagination

Tags: url, pagination, links

On the backend administration area, I am unable to go to any of the pages of articles via the page number links naturally.

The Page links go to:  `http://mydomain.com/C=content_edit&tbl_offset=50`

But should be going to this:  `http://mydomain.com/manager.php?D=cp&channel_id=1&C=content_edit&tbl_offset=50`

How can this be fixed?  Is there a file that needs an edit to it someplace?  For some reason it is not picking up the beginning of the URL after the `mydomain.com` part.

I found a topic that is somewhat similar to mine ( http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/217792/ ), but the fix was specific for Member Sorting, this is not the case in my situation.

Comment: how are you accessing your CP is it via domain.com/admin.php if so you need to edit that and set your CP url as it looks like you are missing admin.php from the url you posted.

Comment: Where do you see admin.php?  I see manager.php, not admin.php!  And yes, looks like he is accessing his admin from `domain.com/manager.php`

Comment: Having the exact same problem? What version of EE are you having this problem with? (2.4.0 here)

Answer (score 1):

It definitely sounds like your control panel URL configuration isn't correct. This needs to be set to match the URL you use to access the control panel, so it can generate the links correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Zenbu module on your EE install to change the Edit page, it may be the source of the issues. Try uninstalling and retest the links.

If you aren't using Zenbu look at all your installed addons to see if any others are making changes to the Edit page.

You can test to see if it's an Extension causing the problem by adding this to your config file which is located here /system/expressionengine/config/config.php:

```
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';
```